# Swift: addSubview not appearing in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I'm having this issue where I'm debugging and I have a breakpoint at the end of this function. When I check it using Capture View Hierarchy, the subview called "overlayView" is nowhere to be seen.

```
import UIKit

class BrowseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    func addOverlayView() {
        let overlayView = UIView()
        overlayView.alpha = 0.6
        overlayView.backgroundColor = .green
        overlayView.frame = self.bounds
        self.imageView.addSubview(overlayView)
        self.bringSubview(toFront: overlayView)
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest debugging tips?

Comment: Shouldn't the frame of the overlay view be based on the bounds of the image view?

Comment: When did you call addOverlayView()?

Comment: Call the function in `awakeWithNib()`. Although I think that you should give the background color of image view rather adding a subview just for color.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please let me know from where you are calling **addOverlayView()**.

I believe it should call from **awakeFromNib()**

Comment: It's from a didSelectCellAt method

Comment: @ScriptKitty If it is calling from **didSelectCellAt**  than please check if **overlay already added** than do not add the overlay.                      Also when you tap on cell than the overlay view visible on **stackview** otherwise its not.                                                                                                         
Let me know if more help required.

Comment: I have checked this, but that is not the problem. The debugger does hit it though. I believe it has to do with allocating the view in the wrong place. When I move that code into `init` it shows just fine.

Comment: @ScriptKitty It's great to hear that you solved the problem. If above steps helps to identified the correct reason of yours problem than can you please rate this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your overlay view in your UIImageView by using `insertSubview` method as shown below:

```
import UIKit

class BrowseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    func addOverlayView() {
        let overlayView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        overlayView.alpha = 0.6
        overlayView.backgroundColor = .green
        self.imageView.insertSubview(_ view: overlayView, at index: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry boys it was a dumb offscreen error. I was using dequeueReusableCell, when I should've used cellForItem(at:). I have added correct code.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! BrowseCell

        cell.addOverlayView()
    }
```